# UI elements backward compatibility

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application that is currently targeting devices having a minimum API of 11. However, I want to modify the app to make it compatible with android versions lower than 3.0. The problem is, I have various UI elements that are only provided in the newer versions:

- Action bar contains menu items. I read that one solution is using the ActionBarSherlock package. However, the activity already extends ListActivity. Is there any other solution?
- Date picker dialog fragment throws an error saying:

"Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.DialogFragment"

This error occurs on the method newFragment.show().
This happens despite having followed the note given on the Android Developer page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the activity already extends ListActivity.

Use ActionBarSherlock and change from `ListActivity` to `SherlockListActivity`.

> What could be the problem?

You are trying to use native API Level 11 fragments instead of the Android Support Library's backport of fragments. IOW, you are using `android.app.DialogFragment` [instead of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html).